# C# Selenium | button is dont have id

Tags: c#, selenium

I want information from you on how to encode this.

As you can see in the picture, there is a part, but it does not appear as a button. That's why I can't find any of his IDs.

I would be glad if you put it in code how to do it.

My Codes (not work);

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/a[2]")).Click();
```

Site Codes;

```
<a onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; openLoginBox()" class="linkbutton">KAYIT/GİRİŞ</a>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPuXZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM7d3.png)

Answer (score 0):

To pinpoint this element you can use the class name and the order, or the text itself.

```
var byText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(., 'KAYIT/GİRİŞ')]"));

var byOrder = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//a[@class='linkbutton'][{orderInDom}]"));
```

Comment: Can you take a look if the variables have value?

Comment: I tried to reach this, but it doesn't redirect from the automated test driver cuz it has protection. You should be testing this from a test server, right? Otherwise it won't work for you either.

Answer (score 0):

Simply grab the element by css and click it.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#link-wrapper > a:nth-child(4"))).click();
```